# Pointer and references in c++ as arguments

Tags: c++

What does this do exactly?

```
void insertar (struct pila *&p);
```

What are advantages of using `*&` versus if the method were only declared like so:

```
void insertar (struct pila *p);
```

or like so:

```
void insertar (struct pila &p);
```

I know that the `*` is pointer and `&` is address, but both in the method signature?

what is the advantage?

And what are they used for?

What does it do?

Comment: The reference allows the called method or function to change the pointer.  If you use the pointer alone, it can't be changed by the call.

Comment: Both `*` and `&` is invalid C (I don't know C++). I suggest you do not attempt to write multi-language source files.

Comment: This allows the pointer `p` to be updated by the function. In C, you would use `void insertar (struct pila **p)`.

Answer (score 5):

You're mixing up two meanings of `&`. It is the "address of" operator when used in an expression. That is, if you have an `int x;` and you do `&x`, you get the address of `x`. However, in a type, the `&` means that it is a reference type. These are two totally separate concepts.

The following takes a `pila`, copying it into the function. Modifying `p` will only effect the copy inside the function:

```
void insertar(pila p);
```

The following takes a `pila` by reference, so that the object inside the function is the same one as outside. Modifying `p` here will modify the object that was passed in:

```
void insertar(pila& p);
```

The following takes a pointer to a `pila`, copying the pointer into the function. Modifying the pointer will only have an effect inside the function. The object it points to is the same as outside however:

```
void insertar(pila* p);
```

The following takes a pointer to a `pila` by reference, so that the pointer inside the function is the same one as outside. If you modify the *pointer*, you'll modify the pointer outside too:

```
void insertar(pila*& p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `&` is a reference. A `*&` is pretty much like a `**`. It will allow you to change a pointer.

```
int u = 3;

void change( int *& p ) {
    p = &u;
}

void main() {
    int *p;
    change( p );
    // p == &u
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`*&` is a reference to a pointer in your example. In short, you can modify the data pointed by the pointer *and* the pointer itself. Example:

```
int global1 = 0, global2 = 1;
void func(int*& p)
{
    *p = 42;
    p = &global1;
}

int main()
{
    int* p = &global2;
    func(p); // Now global2 == 42 and p points to global1 (p == &global1).
}
```